# UIActivityIndicatorView does not work in the mode dispatch_sync

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

I use `UIActivityIndicatorView` in my projet, but it does not work, the follow is my code:

```
let globalQueueDefault = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)

    dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault){

        self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = false
        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

            self.connect()

            sleep(6)
            dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault) { () -> Void in

                self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true                                             
            }
    }
```

I have tried `dispatch_sync` and `dispatch_async`... but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using this queue you are asking for the code to be run in the background, UI code should only be run on the main thread.

Wrapping you activityView in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in

 })
```

Will put that code back on the main thread as should work as expected.

The revised code should look something like

let globalQueueDefault = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in

    self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = false
    self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { [weak self] () -> Void in
         self?.connect()

          sleep(6)

    })

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in

         self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
         self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true                                             
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your code, I think it like follow`dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault){
        self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = false
        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
            self.connect()
            sleep(6)
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true                                             
            }
    }`

Comment: Hello, I tried your code, but it does not work, and the `self.connect()` does not work too, I think the code is in a dead block....?

Comment: please check the revision

Comment: Out of curiosity what is connect? connecting to ? Are you sure its supposed to be in the background, also why are you using sleep ?

Comment: I used `self?.connect()` to download information from internet by json, after I init a view by these informations and show this view, so I need sleep 6 seconde to wait download informations from internet, do you have some advice for this part ? Thank you !

Comment: I see, I would look into basic JSON fetching from URLs and completion blocks which help to alert you when information is ready rather than sleep() it will help a lot in the future :D.

Comment: Thank you ! I will check it too

Answer (score 0):

UIKit generally deals with from Main thread. So whenever you try to update your UI, you should have to put UI related code in main thread as displayed below.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         // All UI related code goes here...
         // I am adding few part of your code here.. Please update this according to your requirement.
         self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
         self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true 
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer is right, but 

SeanLintern88 give me more informations, I will upvote him, I will upvote you next time, Thank you very much for you answer again :)